# && gcc file name &&

Tags: compiling, gcc

Every time I run some codes on VS Code,`cd "file location" && gcc file name.c -o file name && "file location"file name` appears after the device's name and before the result.
I tried to download, before, something for VS Code to use CS50's library using the terminal, and I can't find its location. I want to delete that.

It literally says: `ansar@ansar-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~/Programming$ cd "/home/ansar/Programming/" && gcc Hello.c -o Hello && '/home/ansar/Programming/"Hello Hello, World.`

Sorry for the long question.

Comment: What does your program output?

Comment: The output is 'Hello, World.'